# SwiftUI NavigationView: Keeping back button while removing whitespace

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview

[Screen shot of white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5lyt.png)
I want to remove the empty space below the  <Back button in the second navigation view. I know that this question has been asked several times before, but I have not been able to find a good solution that does this.

I have tried

```
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

and

```
.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
```

without the desired result.

Any hints that  could help me?

```
struct SecondNavView: View {
    let item: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}

struct FirstNavView: View {
    let listItems = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(listItems, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondNavView(item: item)) {
                    Text(item).font(.headline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already have NavigationView in root, so remove second one from FirstNavView. For navigation stack it needs only one NavigationView.

Comment: Hi Aperi, No, the only NavigationView that I have is the one in FirstNavView. ContentView contains only a call to FirstNavView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seens like your parent View hasn't a title, to solve this you need to set  `.navigationTitle` inside `NavigationView` on parent View like this:

```swift
NavigationView {
    
    VStack {
        //....
    }
    
    .navigationTitle(Text("Awesome View"))
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal){
            // Put any view (Text, Image, Stack...) you want here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is do to place of applied modifiers.

The following works (tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5)

[image: demo]

```
struct SecondNavView: View {
    let item: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text(item)
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)  // << here !!
    }
}
```